Fallback an exposed in Vue Composition API?
I have a table component with an exposed:
const self = {
    dispatchKeys: (e: KeyboardEvent) => (onInputKeydown(e), self),
    assign, assignRow, selectCell,
    selection,
    columns,
    get currentRowIdx() {
        return currentIdx.value;
    },
    set currentRowIdx(val) {
        if (val >= items.value.length || val < 0) {
            return;
        }
        currentIdx.value = val;
    },
    get rowCount() {
        return items.value.length
    }
};
defineExpose(self);

Works fine until I try to wrap the component into another with more high-level functionality:
<template>
  <lq-table ...... />
</template>

The problem is that the exposed is lost and I have no idea how to forward the exposed up. I've tried to expose a ref of the wrapped component, proxies, no luck. Any way to expose the child component?

"'ve tried to expose a ref of the wrapped component, proxies" - can you clarify what you tried and what did not work? Generally you just  and expose "table" in this comp. Also consider explaining what you want to achieve in the end, it's not common to expose a lot of data. If it's necessary to access child's data in  parent's template this is often done through slot props, specifically in table comps

@EstusFlask if i expose the child table ref the expose loses its reactivity and stop working ‍♂️ . given tight time constraints i would rather work with the existing exposed than inventing something new, I just wanted to fallback it and it was suddenly a hard task...

@EstusFlask i'm tending to think that the expose isn't that good. given a complex typescript nested configs, @vue/language-tools can't infer exposes, i should type them manually like ComponentExposed<>. so i want to try v-model:expose="table" which will provide the reactive self and would possible avoid the typing (i hope the inferring would work better). but indeed would look strange.

@EstusFlask i need to write some table logic outside slots so a rich exposed is my way to go

Yes, it isn't for several reasons. Accessing instances through refs is commonly considered an antipattern and while there are many valid reasons to do this, it needs to be justified. If you intend to deeply mutate data, it's bad in a similar way as deeply mutating props, only in reverse. Any way, it's doable, reactivity works there the same way as in other places, there's no problem https://t.ly/pILU3 . Please, provide a way to reproduce. It depends on your case how it's supposed to be done properly. Probably through callbacks or two-way binding. But I'm sure deep refs are a workaround

@EstusFlask added a playground into the answer where i try to expose a reactive set

Should be c.value.c.selection.add('item1'), then it's fine

@EstusFlask oops, but i don't want the double ref since the usage should be the same as the original

It normally won't be better. That you have a workaround that looks like a workaround seems ok to me. For what you ask it would likely be defineExpose(new Proxy<GrandChildType>(...)) in a child. Doable but smells fishy. Usually you're supposed to interact with a grand child in known ways, so you create several exposed wrapper methods in a child, and there will be no such problem in general. It's almost better to expose methods instead of data, at least they can be easily debugged, as opposed to deeply mutated data. Any way, custom proxy is the answer

@EstusFlask, i already have const config = makeTableConfig(...); <lq-table :config, so ended with const [config, $table] = makeTableConfig where $table is the exposed ref, looks good and no need in the template ref

Yes, makes sense to manipulate data this way. Also I doubt a proxy would work. I'd expect defineExpose to expect static set of exposed keys, while it doesn't exist at the time it's called in child's setup
